# Extending Object implicity

Tags: java, object, inheritance, extends

Everyone knows that Object is the super class and all the classes which does not extend any other class will extend Object class implicitly. I want to know how this implicit extends works.

Comment: What do you mean "how it works"? The Java compiler simply treats every class that doesn't use an `extends FooBar` as if it had `extends java.lang.Object` instead. There's nothing more magical about it than that.

Answer (score 2):

We have a file child.java

```
class Child
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Child().toString());
    }
}
```

As we can see from the above code, in fact, the parent class of the Child class is Object, so we can use the public or protected resources of the Object class, such as the toString method, in Child. So how do the Java compiler and JVM do it?

Knowing this reason doesn't really need to know the implementation details of the JVM. Just think about the principles of this virtual machine program. Generally speaking, there are two ways to deal with the default inheritance problem for such languages running on virtual machines (such as Java.).

1. During compiling the source code stage, if encountering a class without a parent class, the compiler will assign it a default parent class (usually Object), and If the virtual machine processes the class, since the class already has A default parent class, so the VM will still handle each class in the usual way. In this case, from a compiled binary perspective, all classes will have a parent class.
2. The compiler still compiles with the actual code and does not do extra processing. If a class does not explicitly inherit from other classes, and the compiled code still has no parent class. Then when the binary code is run by the virtual machine, if a class without a parent class is encountered, the class is automatically treated as a subclass of the Object class (generally the default parent class is Object).

As can be seen from the above two cases, the first case is an article made on the compiler, that is, when there is no parent class, the compiler automatically assigns a parent class to it at compile time. The second case is to make a fuss on the virtual machine, that is, the default parent class is added by the virtual machine.

So which is the case of Java? In fact, we could get this answer by using javap. Just look for a decompilation tool and decompile the .class file to see how the compiler is compiled. Take the above code as an example. If it is the first case, even if the Child has no parent class since the compiler has automatically added an Object parent class to Child, the Child class in the source code obtained after decompilation is Inherited from the Object class. If this is not the case, then the second case.

First, compile child.java to Child.class

```
%javac child.java
```

Now we use the decompilation tool javap with JDK to decompile Child.class, first execute the following command:

```
 % javap -c Child
```

After the command, we have our bytecode in a somewhat-readable form, where we can identify our methods, integers, commands, and strings

```
class Child {
  Child();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1         // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic  #2 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new     #3 // class Child
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #4         // Method "<init>":()V
      10: invokevirtual #5         // Method java/lang/Object.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      13: invokevirtual #6         // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      16: return
}
```

As can be seen from the above the piece of code, Test has been inherited from Object, so it can be concluded that Java is the first case of the property, that is, the compiler specifies Object as its default parent class for the class without the parent class.

Comment: Even simpler would be to compare the `javap` output of a trivial `class Foo {}` with `class Foo extends Object {}`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, For all versions before JDK6, you are right. Using the javap decompiled Child class explicitly inherit Object. but JDK 7 and later will not show explicitly 'extends Object'. 
That is to say, JDK 6 is the compiler processing, and JDK 7 is the virtual machine processing.